# cv2 imshow right click dropdown menu disappears immediately

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Problem**

[image: problem illustration]

When I use cv imshow with the code below, I cannot use the right click to see the dropdown menu.

**Code**

```
import cv2
image_path = "/nas/data/IST/FODCam/230216/c6/p838_v4/85349980.jpg"
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 900, 600)
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Detailed Explanation**

- What happens is I just see the border of the menu for a very short
  time. It seems like it starts opening but maybe just after some
  milliseconds it decides to close.

  Note that in the same computer, in the same cv setup (same conda
  environment), with another code, I achieve opening it and it looks
  like this:

  [image: cv dropdown menu image]
- I tried different cv2.namedWindow flags, I tried to use
  cv2.setMouseCallback to cancel that effect on EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN. I
  was expecting to see the problem disappears.
- I have realized that this is not related to code. The same code can work as desired. Then I discovered that the problem arises when the cell including the code in Jupyter Notebook(in VsCode) runs again. If I restart the notebook and run the cell, it is OK. When I run the second time without restarting, it is problematic. So my current workaround is "always restart the notebook" But I still do not know why this happens.

Comment: You are missing Drive path. Should be `image_path = "C:/nas/data/IST/FODCam/230216/c6/p838_v4/85349980.jpg"` or whatever drive path you set.

Comment: Thanks @toyotaSupra for the kindly help. This is Linux environment where, unlike Windows, absolute paths look llike the one as I used. (https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/navigating-linux-filesystem#:~:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20the,%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fls%20.)